# CSS suggestions don't show up

Tags: ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am currently working in PhpStorm and closed the project yesterday evening as usual, as well as started it as usual today.

But now when I type CSS code I don't get any recommendations / auto completion suggestions.

The only difference is that I have a new keyboard today, everything else is the same as yesterday.

Edit:

Here is a screenshot as requested:

[image]

It doesn't work in one specific file, in the other files it is working fine, here is the file where it doesn't work:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="flex justify-center ">
    <div class="w-11/12 bg-gray-400 p-6 rounded-lg font-serif text-4xl font-bold bg-opacity-70 subpixel-antialiased tracking-wide not-italic">
        <div class="p-10 shadow-2xl mb-10 bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500 border-solid border-2 border-black rounded-lg">
            <div class="bg-gray-100 shadow-2xl border-solid border-2 border-gray-500 rounded-lg">

                <h1 class="pt-2 pl-4 text-4xl font-bold text-gray-900 title-font mb-8 underline">
                    {{ $post->Titel }}
                </h1>

                <div class="flex-grow">
                    <div>
                        <div class="pt-2 pl-4 pb-3 ml-8 font-medium text-base font-bold font-serif"> Standort: {{ $post->Standort }}</div>
                        <div class="pt-2 pl-4 pb-3 ml-8 font-medium text-base font-bold font-serif"> Kontakt: {{ $post->Kontakt }}</div>
                        <div class="pt-2 pl-4 pb-3 ml-8 font-medium text-base font-bold font-serif"> Startdatum: {{ $post->startdate }}</div>
                        <div class="pt-2 pl-4 pb-3 ml-8 font-medium text-base font-bold font-serif mb-8"> Enddatum: {{ $post->enddate }}</div>
                        <div class="flex-grow ml-5 ml-8 mb-5 content md:w-3/4 pr-4 text-lg text-justify tracking-widest leading-loose mr-7 subpixel-antialiased">
                            {!! $post->Beschreibung !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pt-2 pl-4 mb-2 ml-8 font-medium text-base font-bold font-serif"> Referenzcode: {{ $post->id }}</div>
           
                <div class="flex justify-end font-medium text-base font-bold font-serif mb-5 ml-8 mr-8">
                    <a href="{{ route('bewerben', $post->id) }}">
                        <button type="submit" class="text-white px-4 py-3 rounded text-base font-medium
                                bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500 float-right shadow transition
                                duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100">Direkt bewerben!
                        </button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Comment: @TariqAhmed lol, really helpful answer. I am very happy and satisfied with PhpStorm and I worked with other JetBrains IDE's aswell, so I know my way around better

Comment: @Frevelman What's so special about this file (any visual differences that you can see)? Show a screenshot of how it looks (whole IDE window -- need to see the code and editor tab/file icon). Ideally if you use either default light or standard Darcula theme (as custom themes will have own colors for certain elements that usually will give some hints for some cases). Please also locate the file in the Project View, select that file there and show what `View | Quick Documentation` shows for that file.

Comment: Hey @LazyOne :) The weird thing is in this file it worked yesterday, it is no new file or something like that. I will update the post with the things you suggested, wait a second please

Comment: I've tried your file in a test project using PhpStorm 2021.2.3 and it looks just fine there. I do not have TailwindCSS but normal CSS (Bootstrap) styles are offered with no visible issues. Will it work if you copy-paste the file content into another file (in the same folder as well as in another folder)? If it will work -- will it work if you copy-paste whole file into another folder? Right now I do not see anything unusual from the screenshot alone. I may suggest the following: 1) just restart whole Mac. 2) Try "File | Invalidate Caches..." and restart the IDE and wait for reindex.

Comment: @LazyOne yeah I tried the steps you recommended and it didn't work, I restarted it as well but the issue was still occurring. 

However, I then restarted it again because of another reason and now it works. I assume it was some kind of bug, since it is weird that it only affects one file in a folder with others. Thank you for your time!